# XCode archive error: Negative length at /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/PackageApplication line 293

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I archive my application then go to "Organiser" and click "Share" I select "ipa" and then click "Next" and get an error saying "Negative length at /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/PackageApplication line 293.". I've Googled it but found nothing for this?

EDIT:

It's weird because if when I share I use the "Developer Profile" it works but if I select the Distribution Certificate it comes up with the error. I've regenerated the certificate and provisioning profile but still no joy!

Please advise.

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it, I archieved the application with my Distribution Certificate. Then when clicking "Share" if you select "Don't resign" it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe make a mistake when you archive,check it again,most of these issues because of certificate. Best regards.

Comment: I've made sure it is building "Ad Hoc" with Distribution Certificate. I've regenerated the profile and certificates! I hate xCode sometimes!

Comment: Well,let me see...what about sdk 4.x when you  building "Ad Hoc" ?